# How to define a variable with spreadsheet cell value for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-sheets

I want to define a javascript variable with google spreadsheet value.

The Range is B2

It will be executed on wordpress site ..

First I want to define a variable with cell value .. And then I want to use that variable for innerHtml of

element.

I'm new to javascript.

Pls give the format of code and I will modify that code. with my spreadsheetId

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to execute your code to?

### **1. Using Google Apps Script**

If you want to save a cell value as a variable, you need to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation):

`var cellValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();`

After that you can use your variable in your Apps Script code.

### **2. Using Node JS**

If you're using the [NodeJS](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) library, you need to read the file using a async function with some methods:

```
   const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: 'ID',
    range: 'Sheet Name!range',
  }
```

For more info visit the documentation on:
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sheets/classes/Resource$Spreadsheets.html

Comment: It will be executed on wordpress site ..

First I want to define a variable  with cell value ..

And then I want to use that variable for innerHtml of <p> element 

Thank you

Comment: May I get the answer, is it possible to do that task ?

Comment: not possible... look for a plugin